# Why does database rollback on creating a new comment? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have an issue I've been trying to fix for about the past week. I am trying to create a nested commenting system using the closure_tree gem. I finally figured out how to pass the parent_id as part of the params and now the entire hash is filled correctly in the server log, however every time I try to save a reply my log shows a rollback before the comment is saved. All comments belong_to wad.

Here is the relevant code in my Comment controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_wad
    before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update, :comment_owner, :comment_params]
    before_action :comment_owner, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]

    def create
        if params[:comment][:parent_id].to_i > 0
            parent = Comment.find_by(params[:comment].delete(:parent_id))
            @comment = parent.children.build(comment_params)
            parent_id = parent.id

        else
            @comment = @wad.comments.build(comment_params)
            parent_id = @comment.id
        end
            @comment.user_id = current_user.id
            @comment.save

        if @comment.save
            flash[:success] = 'Your comment was successfully added!'
            redirect_to wad_path(@wad)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end


    def new
        @comment = Comment.new(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
    end

private

    def find_wad
        @wad = Wad.find(params[:wad_id])
    end

    def find_comment
        @comment = @wad.comments.find_by(params[:id])
    end

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :wad_id, :user_id, :parent_id)
    end


    def comment_owner
        unless current_user.id == @comment.user_id
            flash[:notice] = "Action Restricted"
            redirect_to @wad

        end
    end
end
```

Here is the reply form I'm using in my _reply partial in comments view:

```
<%= form_for([@wad, @comment]) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Here is what happens in my server log when I try to input a reply comment:

```
Started POST "/wads/1/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-04 14:20:04 -0800
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LYk07p6h3+RJ6kfx+rixaGJ0a56XPt29v7mFFbCQ+H+Gr5PjzzkrWOWfShCuKwFEIShwEz8Om7IsLjGI3hN0vw==", "comment"=>{"parent_id"=>"136", "content"=>"elmle"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "wad_id"=>"1"}
  Wad Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "wads".* FROM "wads" WHERE "wads"."id" = ? ORDER BY "wads"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE (136) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

There is no attr_accessor in any of my models - just the has_many and belongs_to relationships which are defined properly. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Wad Model:

```
class Wad < ApplicationRecord
     acts_as_votable
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
      default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
      validates :user_id, presence: true
      validates :category, presence: true
      validates :long_form, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1000 }
      validates :short_form, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
      validates :problem_state, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    end
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tree order: 'created_at DESC'
  belongs_to :wad
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Relevant part of User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_voter
  has_many :wads, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
```

Comment: It looks like it cannot find the user.

Comment: in the `else` block when you check `if @comment.save` you should read `.errors.full_messages` to see why it failed. You can assign them to an instance variable and show them in the `new` template.

Comment: Thanks for that @maxpleaner. The error is ["Wad must exist"], but wad #1 does exist and wad_id is present in params?

Comment: Btw, duplication of `@comment.save` makes no sense, because in this case you are making a transaction two times

Comment: @AKovtunov noted. This wasn't there initially but ended up there after days of refactoring just trying to get something to work.

Comment: `@comment = parent.children.build(comment_params)` creates comment from params['comment'], right? So `wad_id` is not going to the comment params. So `@comment.save` returns you an error, because there is no wad_id in the comment object.

Comment: @O.Don you should show your model. I don't know how the `wad` dependency is defined.

Comment: @maxpleaner just updated post to include models

Comment: @O.Don I think you just need to use `wad_id` instead of `parent_id` when you create the comment

Comment: @maxpleaner but the comment already belongs to the wad and the relationship is working correctly. parent_id is used to relate a comment to another comment. Don't I have to pass the id of the root comment in order to establish the relationship? or am I misunderstanding

Comment: @O.Don You're calling `Comment.new` and just passing a parent_id. Try passing the wod to that constructor. Beyond that I'm out of ideas since I'm not familiar with this gem.

Comment: @maxpleaner thanks a lot! this fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the logs, params are:

```
{"comment"=>{"parent_id"=>"136", "content"=>"elmle"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "wad_id"=>"1"}
```

In this case we are going to this condition:

```
if params[:comment][:parent_id].to_i > 0
  parent = Comment.find_by(params[:comment].delete(:parent_id))
  @comment = parent.children.build(comment_params)
  parent_id = parent.id
```

where new Comment object is created from `params["comment"]` that contain only `parent_id` and `content`.
So new object is being created without `wad_id` key that is required by `belongs_to` that you probably have in your model

Comment: Thanks, I see what you are saying. Please pardon me if this is a bad question but why does params["comment"] not get wad_id even though wad_id is in comment_params?

Comment: @O.Don it is in the `params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :wad_id, :user_id, :parent_id)` and your `"wad_id"` is outside the `comment` hash of `params` variable

Comment: But I don't understand why it's outside or what the difference is between comment_params and the "comment hash of params variable"?

Comment: @O.Don `comment_params` is equal to `params[:comment]`. Now let's take a look at your params from the log. `wad_id` comes outside the `params[:comment]` it's in the `params[:wad_id]` but **not** in the `params[:comment][:wad_id]`

Comment: To solve your issue, you need to put your `:wad_id` inside the `:comment` section of params or do `@comment.wad_id = params[:wad_id]` that is not good from design point of view.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
Comment.find_by(params[:comment].delete(:parent_id))
```

you delete your :parent_id from the hash of params[:comment], you need to remove from permit in your comment_params. Try to change your method like this, it should work:

```
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :wad_id, :user_id)
end
```

**EDIT**
Also I think you need to change the first command in

```
parent = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment].delete(:parent_id))
```

or

```
 parent = Comment.find(params[:comment].delete(:parent_id))
```

Comment: These changes result with the same ["Wad must exist"] error